# Making a heading for files created in emacs

Tags: emacs

I've been a pretty adamant user of nano as my text editor for quite awhile for sake of simplicity. However, now I'm becoming a bit more "seasoned" and wanted to step up to a big-boy editor like emacs.

I know that emacs is highly customizable, and thought of something that I'd like to do.
Is there a way to create a generic heading for files created of a certain filetype?

For example, if I make a .* file, could I generate something similar to Xcode's generated "heading"?

```
//*************************************************************
//
//  filename.*
//
//  Created by some_static_user on MM/DD/YY.
//  Copyright (c) YYYY some_static_user. All rights reserved.
//
//*************************************************************
```

It would be lovely and save me some time. Besides, I know there are some emacs apologists who would love to make an emac user out of me.

Thanks for your time and I hope this isn't too trivial.

erip

Comment: A ".*" file?  As in, a file whose name literally ends with a period and an asterisk?

Comment: Sean, I mean any generic filetype. If it type 'emacs helloworld.c', I want it to read 'helloworld.c' instead of 'filename.*'

Comment: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutomaticFileHeaders

Comment: A search at S.O. for AutomaticFileHeaders also turns up [License banners for Scala when using ENSIME](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981544/license-banners-for-scala-when-using-ensime/4910996).

Comment: FWIW there's a related blog on that at [emacsworld.blogspot.com](http://emacsworld.blogspot.com/2008/12/generating-automatic-file-headers.html). itsjeyd, you should add your link as a proper answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: @erip I'm glad you were able to come up with a solution based on my input, and thanks for taking the time to describe your solution. For future reference, instead of posting the solution as a comment, consider [adding an actual answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). After 48 hours, you will even be able to [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) to make it stand out as the correct one for future visitors. (The reason why I posted a comment instead of an answer is that link-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/244644)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it figured out based on @itsjeyd 's answer. For those Mac users reading this, add this to your `~/.emacs.d/init.el`

```
(add-to-list 'load-path' "~/.emacs.d/")     
(autoload 'auto-make-header "header2")     
(add-hook 'write-file-hooks 'auto-update-file-header)     
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'auto-make-header)     
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'auto-make-header)     
(add-hook 'tex-mode-hook 'auto-make-header)
```

after saving `header2.el` in the same directory as `init.el`. Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Try library [`header2.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/header2.el).
Description [**here**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutomaticFileHeaders#toc2). You should be able to customize things to get just what you want.